# PowerShell Runspace in Silverlight Class Library (shared with WPF class library)

Tags: silverlight, powershell, assembly-resolution

I have a Silverlight Library project that is linked to from a WPF application (shared `.xaml` and `.cs` code).

I am trying to add a class to start powershell runspace and execute some commands. Yet I cannot add the reference to the Silverlight library and I get this error:

[image: cannot add reference : it was not built against Silverlight runtime]

What reference should I add to Silverlight library so I can invoke PowerShell cmdlets?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as you've discovered because the PowerShell engine was built against the desktop CLR. You create another C# library to put the PowerShell code into.  You could also put the code into a Portable Class library that targets both NET 4.0 and Silverlight 4 and higher.  I was able to successfully add a reference to the System.Management.Automation assembly but that's no guarantee it will work.